# Get information no matter number of childs in Firebase (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my tree:

[image]

I want to get the `d` value (`"its d"`)

But I do not get any information printed

```
ref.queryOrderedByChild("userA")
            .observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
                if snapshot.exists() {
                    for child in (snapshot.value?.allValues)! {
                        if let fruits = child["c"] as? [String:String]{
                            let name = fruits["d"]
                            print(name)
                            }
                    }
```

Comment: can you explain more ...I don't understand term "no matter number of childs in Firebase" ...

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 It means for example I got 200 childs and I want to get the last child's value

Comment: I don't think so its possible with this structure .... you need to go through that key to get last value ...

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 Ok, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the answer to specific question:

> Get information no matter number of childs in Firebase

not sure if it's what you are looking for however.

To get to 'd', you don't need a query. You can directly access that data.

Here's my structure (matching yours)

```
"the_users" : {
    "a" : {
      "b" : {
        "c" : {
          "d" : "It's d"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

and the code to get to the 'd' value

```
let theUsersRef = rootRef.child("the_users")
let dRef = theUsersRef.child("a/b/c/d")
dRef.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
     let msg = snapshot.value as! String
     print(msg)
})
```

and the output

```
It's d
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `queryOrderedByChild("userA")`, it tells the database to order by the primitive value of the `userA` property. Since in your JSON there is no `userA` property with a primitive value, the order by statement is meaningless.

You don't filter the data in the query, so you will get a snapshot with all data at the location where you attach the listener. It's unclear from your code sample what location that is, but it's very likely that it's higher in the JSON tree than where a child `c` exists. So that means that you're not printing any name.

It would probably a lot clearer if you simple print all children:

```
ref.queryOrderedByChild("userA")
   .observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
       if snapshot.exists() {
           for child in (snapshot.value?.allValues)! {
               print(child.key)
               if let fruits = child["c"] as? [String:String]{
                   let name = fruits["d"]
                   print(name)
               }
           }
       }
   })
```